# Can't use tkinter's config function to set pady to a tuple

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

So I want to reconfigure some of my rows to have a higher padding on the bottom but I can't seem to use the config function with a tuple.

This code below returns a `_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "0 5"`.

```
    for k in [2,5,7]:
        self.accounts[k].config(pady = (0,5), bg = "yellow")
    #accounts is a list of frames
```

Comment: does it support tuples? grid and pack does, but does label itself allow pad tuples as an input?

Comment: I guess not. I didn't realize that that was the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widgets don't accept a padding that is a tuple. The tuple is only supported as arguments to `pack` and `grid`. You'll need to specify the `pady` by calling `grid_configure`, assuming you're using `grid`.

```
for k in [2,5,7]:
    self.accounts[k].config(bg = "yellow")
    self.accounts[k].grid_configure(pady = (0,5))
```